# How to permanently 'eject' my amazon kindle

Tags: 16.04, usb

Whenever I unmount the kindle so as to charge it via the computer and read while I am updating the system I eject the kindle using the launcher in Unity. However one thing I have noticed is that the kindle is soon connected again and sadly I cannot read my books. because the kindle goes into USB drive mode. Is there some way to prevent this and make sure that the kindle is not re-connected every-time I eject it.

> TL;DR Version: Kindle is reconnected after I eject it (from launcher). How to prevent this and get kindle to charge and read mode while connected to Ubuntu desktop

Comment: Newer Android versions have the charge-only mode. Maybe your Kindle as something to the effect?

Comment: @MichaelBay. Nope or at least not any option which I can find. The only way to charge it without getting into USB mode is to lock it and let it charge